# How to access 'updateOn' option inside custom implementation of ControlValueAccessor in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have to following form

```
form = new FormGroup({
   title: new FormControl(null, {updateOn: 'blur'}),
})
```

And for the title input I created a custom control `title-input` that implements `ControlValueAccessor`. How can I access `updateOn` option inside this control?

Comment: you can get de propety with  this:   form.get("title").updateOn . but you will get "blur". if u want listen changes try: form.get("title").valueChanges.subscribe(change => console.log(change));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some googling I found two solutions:

#### Solution #1:

Note, there is no `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` provider.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-input',
    templateUrl: './my-input.component.html',
    styles: [],
})  
export class MyInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit {
    onChange: (_: any) => void;
    onTouched: () => void;
    isDisabled: boolean;
    value: string;

    constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {
        ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Update On: ', this.ngControl.control.updateOn);
    }
}
```

### Solution #2.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-input',
    templateUrl: './my-input.component.html',
    styles: [],
    providers: [
    {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyInputComponent),
        multi: true,
    },
    ],
})
export class MyInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit {
    onChange: (_: any) => void;
    onTouched: () => void;
    isDisabled: boolean;
    value: string;

    ngControl: NgControl;

    constructor(private inj: Injector) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.ngControl = this.inj.get(NgControl);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log('Update on:', this.ngControl.control.updateOn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the updateOn value when using CVA?

Comment: yes, it is possible, look at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35005