# Control Value Accessor Directive to run on blur instead of "input"

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

I created a Control Value Accessor directive. I would like it to update the model on blur, instead of on input (i.e keydown). How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Rely on the `NgControl` injection and the native events of your html input like so

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jfruhu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcva%2Fcva.component.ts%3AL28)

```js
export class CvaComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @ViewChild('input', { static: true }) input!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  private _change: Function;
  private _touch: Function;

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() private ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (this.ngControl) this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.ngControl.control.updateOn === 'blur')
      fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'blur').subscribe(() =>
        this.ngControl.control.setValue(this.input.nativeElement.value)
      );
    else
      fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'input').subscribe(() =>
        this.ngControl.control.setValue(this.input.nativeElement.value)
      );
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.input.nativeElement.value = obj;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this._change = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this._touch = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.input.nativeElement.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting "Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for NgControl. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200". I have a directive whilst your exemple is with a component.

Comment: @Olivvv you could prevent that circular dependency with the solution 2 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58614696/2940802